# FB Graph API - How do I detect if a page was merged and get the ID of the right page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Pages can be merged using this procedure https://www.facebook.com/help/249601088403018. After the merge one of the pages redirects to the other.

Is the only way to detect this by fetching the page and see if Facebook does a redirect? Or is there no way to use the Graph API to get this information?

Comment: what's the API response when you query the merged page (whats the page ID)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this answer is probably coming 1 year too late, but this question was asked *and answered* by Baz at [Programmatically detect if a Facebook page was merged with another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734572/programmatically-detect-if-a-facebook-page-was-merged-with-another-page). I've tested his solution on the Graph API Explorer and it works. To quote [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25735582/4474020),

> There is a field called "best_page" that gives the best alternate id of the page you are querying.

He specifies

> If the page you are querying is already the best page, you will not receive any "best_page" property in the response

He extrapolates by saying,

> if you are querying all of a user's likes, and would like to know the best page of each without having to re-query each page individually, you can use it with the `likes` endpoint:
>
> ```
> /v2.1/me/likes?fields=id,name,best_page{id}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Just wanna add my two cents to this. Another behavior I've come across is the graph API throwing an error, mentioning that the page has been migrated and should be referenced by a new ID:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Page ID 763809000301020 was migrated to page ID 697230513732818.  Please update your API calls to the new ID", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 21
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.  Once a page has been merged the Graph API will no longer provide data on that Page using the old Page ID.

I do not believe there is any indicator that the page has been merged a Graph API layer.