# Programmatically detect if a Facebook page was merged with another page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook has begun "merging" duplicate pages. For example if you visit this page for the movie Good Fellas: https://www.facebook.com/105652212803097, you will notice that it redirects to the now main page: https://www.facebook.com/goodfellasthemovie while displaying the following message: `"Goodfellas was merged with this page"`

This is great, but users' likes were also copied from the "old" page to the "new" page without being removed from the "old" page. So if you query a user's likes who liked a page that was merged, you will get 2 separate like ids for what are now the same page - without indication of a relationship between the pages, or that one of the likes was automatically generated.

Is there any way to programmatically detect whether a page has been merged with another page? Or that two pages are related to each other? Or that a page is no longer functional and redirects?

Answer (score 3):

Since posting the question I found the answer.

There is a field called "best_page" that gives the best alternate id of the page you are querying. Using the original example of the movie Good Fellas, if you query any of their "bad" pages with the "best_page" field, for example page id 102154619826846, if the page is not already the best page you will get back a "best_page" property that points to the main page id of 193801173989136:

```
{
  "id": "102154619826846", 
  "name": "Good Fellas", 
  "best_page": {
    "category": "Movie", 
    "name": "Goodfellas", 
    "id": "193801173989136"
  }
}
```

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=102154619826846%2F%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cbest_page&version=v2.1

If the page you are querying is already the best page, you will not receive any "best_page" property in the response:

```
{
  "id": "193801173989136", 
  "name": "Good Fellas"
}
```

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=193801173989136%2F%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cbest_page&version=v2.1

To extend the solution, if you are querying all of a user's likes, and would like to know the best page of each without having to re-query each page individually, you can use it with the `likes` endpoint:

```
/v2.1/me/likes?fields=id,name,best_page{id}
```

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Flikes%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cbest_page%7Bid%7D&version=v2.1

This will return all of your likes with a "best_page" property for each like that has a better page. Similar to above, only pages that are not already the best page will return a "best_page" property.

Comment: How did you find the id 193801173989136?